# Rails 6 building a quiz application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

I'm building a quiz in Rails 6 and using nested forms. I'm not too sure if this is the right way to do things, but i'm looking for a solution on how to submit multiple quiz questions before a user submits the entire quiz and thought this approach may work. But, I'm stuck on how best to iterate through each question and have a user submit an option, click next and go on to the next question until all are completed?

For example. A quiz can have 10 questions. One question appears on the page at at time for the user to select an option and click next to show the next question. After the tenth and final question, the user then submits the quiz. It also saves their answer in the Quiz Answer database as well as creating a single record attached to the user for the Quiz.

I have the following setup:

**Quiz**

```
has_many :quiz_answers, dependent: :destroy
accepts_nested_attributes_for :quiz_answers, allow_destroy: true
```

**Quiz Answer**

```
belongs_to :quiz, optional: true
```

These next two create the Quiz question and options (ie. Potential answers) which are setup by an admin. This allows questions to be added and taken out as needed on the fly. This part works as it should and I have no issues here.

**Quiz Question**

```
has_many :quiz_options, dependent: :destroy
accepts_nested_attributes_for :quiz_options, allow_destroy: true
```

**Quiz Option**

```
belongs_to :quiz_question, optional: true
```

**Controller**

```
class QuizzesController < ApplicationController
 def new
    @quiz = Quiz.new
    @quiz_question = QuizQuestion.where(active: true)
    @quiz.quiz_answers.build
  end
 
def create
    @quiz = Quiz.new(quiz_params)
   
    respond_to do |format|
      if @quiz.save
        format.html { redirect_to quiz_url(@quiz), notice: "Quiz was successfully created." }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @quiz }
      else
        format.html { render :new, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        format.json { render json: @quiz.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
end
```

**Form**

```
<%= form_with(model: quiz) do |form| %>
 <%= form.fields_for :quiz_answers do |builder| %>
  <%= render 'quiz_answer', form: builder %>
 <% end %>
 <%= form.submit "Submit", class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
<% end %>
```

**Partial**

```
<% @quiz.each do |question| %>
 <h2><%= question.question %></h2>
  <% question.quiz_options.each do |o| %>
   <%= form.radio_button :answer, o.answer %> <%= o.answer %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

**Schema**

```
create_table "quizzes", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "user_id"
  end

create_table "quiz_answers", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "quiz_id"
    t.integer "quiz_question_id"
    t.integer "quiz_option_id"
    t.integer "user_id"
    t.string "question"
    t.string "answer"
    t.boolean "correct"
    t.integer "score"
  end

  create_table "quiz_options", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "quiz_question_id"
    t.string "answer"
    t.boolean "correct", default: false
  end

  create_table "quiz_questions", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "quiz_id"
    t.string "question"
    t.boolean "active", default: true
  end
```

Comment: Maybe create the quiz and questions when the user starts the quiz and then cycle through the already created questions?

Comment: Yep, that's what I'm trying to achieve. But falling short on how to cycle through the created questions in the quiz form.

Comment: Like how to get from question 4 to question 5 when they submit 4? What about `quiz.questions.where('id > ?', @question.id).order(:id).first`? Sorry I don't know the Rails 7 recommended syntax for where queries. This should give you the 5th question.